# How to close setup window when running installed application by Inno Setup?

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup to install WinForms utility and it works fine.

There's a minor problem that our users find quite annoying: On last step of installation, Inno Setup suggests to launch the utility that has just been installed. Most of the users want to immediately launch and (and so do I). 
The problem is that the setup window of Inno Setup is not closed until the user closes the installed utility. Furthermore, you can't close the setup window unless you close the installed utility first.
The attached image demonstrates the installed utility (the right icon) and the Inno's setup icon (the left one).

So how to fix that problem? Please advice. Thank you

The problem occurs on all Windows: XP, 7, 2003, 2008 etc.

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're having trouble with. When you use the `postinstall` flag in the `[Run]` section, you will get a *Run after install* check box, which if you keep checked and finish the wizard launches the specified application and closes the wizard window. Could you elaborate on your problem ? Do you have a recent version of InnoSetup ?

Comment: Please make sure you have NOT selected flags `waituntilidle` or `waituntilterminated`

Comment: @TLama, yes I have postinstall there. Yes I keep it checked. The problem is that the wizard window is not closed while the application is launched.

RobeN No I don't have those flags

Comment: Then I can't reproduce what you described. Could you post your script part with which we'll be able to reproduce the problem ? And are you using recent version of InnoSetup ?

Comment: Thank you. I use 5.4.3 (a).
Is this the part you mean?


[Run]
Filename: {app}\myexe.exe; Description: Launch my app; Flags: postinstall skipifsilent

Comment: Yes, without the `nowait` flag I could reproduce the problem. Solution is below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the [`nowait`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm#nowait) flag to that [`[Run]`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm) section entry. So modify your script like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\myexe.exe; Description: Launch my app; Flags: postinstall skipifsilent nowait
```